# Using free with realloc

Tags: c, sockets, malloc, free, realloc

i am trying to use realloc for synamically allocating memory to array while reading from socket .. evrything is working fine but it is giving error when i am using free in main. i actually need to get data in usr_data and send it to different functions for processing.

```
*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x083fc008 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the function:

```
int read_from_socket(int connfd,char **usr_str)
{
printf("\nusr_data : %s\n",*usr_str);
int count = 0, bytesread = 0;
char *temp;
char buf[MAX] = {0};
while((bytesread = read(connfd,buf,BLOCKSIZE))>0)
{
    temp = NULL;
    count = count + bytesread;
    temp = (char *)realloc(*usr_str, count);
    if(NULL == temp)
    {
        printf("\nMemory Error\n");
        return FAILURE;
    }
    *usr_str = temp;
    printf("\nadd in: %lu",*usr_str);
    memcpy(((*usr_str) + count - bytesread),buf, MAX);
    printf("\nadd in2: %lu",*usr_str);
    if((*usr_str)[count-1] == '$')
    {
       (*usr_str)[count-1] = '\0';
       printf("\nData received: %s\n",*usr_str);
       printf("\nadd in2: %lu",*usr_str);
       break;
    }
}
}
```

AND HERE is The code i am using in main

```
for(;;)
{
printf("I am waiting-----Start of Main Loop\n");
len=sizeof(cliaddr);
connfd=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&len);
if ( connfd < 0)
{
    if (errno == EINTR)
    printf("Interrupted system call ??");
    continue;
}
printf("Connection from %s\n",inet_ntop(AF_INET,&cliaddr.sin_addr,buf,sizeof(buf)));
while(1)
{
    usr_data = NULL;
    read_from_socket(connfd,&usr_data);
    printf("\nusr_dat: %s    %lu\n",usr_data,usr_data);
    if(!strcmp(usr_data,"exit"))
    {
        break;
    }
    printf("\nadd: %lu\n",usr_data);
    free(usr_data);
}
close(connfd);
printf("\nFINISHED SERVING ONE CLIENT\n");
}
```

actually the server keeps on running in the read loop until it gets exit from user...

can any one point out why.. glibc error with free()

Comment: char *usr_data is declared in main befor for loop.

Comment: In `memcpy(((*usr_str) + count - bytesread),buf, MAX);` are you sure you are not writing past the alloc'ed storage ??

Comment: *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x083fc008 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: My guess is, you are copying more bytes than allocation.. pls check.

Comment: no if i remove free in main it is working but memory leaks are dere(obviously) and i actually need to get data in usr_data and send it to different functions for processing

Comment: Just because it's working doesn't mean it's correct. Often heap buffer overruns will corrupt internal heap data which will cause any following malloc or free to crash.

Comment: A blatant memory leak is **not** "working". It is a sign of invoking undefined behavior if it crashes when you free(). You're passing the *same* pointer to `read_from_socket()` after invoking `free()` but without resetting it to NULL and allowing the `malloc()` behavior of `realloc()` on a NULL pointer. Second, this line: `memcpy(((*usr_str) + count - bytesread),buf, MAX);` is all-but **guaranteed** to be wrong. Show us what MAX is, then think about whether MAX could *ever* be larger than `bytesRead` (which it likely *always* is). You should be using `bytesRead` for that parameter; not MAX.

Comment: As ever, _do not cast the pointer that `malloc` (or any other `*alloc` function) returns_. In C, you don't have to, in fact: not casting is in some ways safer.

Comment: Yes Finally solved it the problem was with memcpy.. MAX was set to 1024 while bytesread was less than MAX.. stupid me.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
memcpy(((*usr_str) + count - bytesread),buf, bytesread);
```

should do it. If *bytesread* is less than *MAX* your version copies beyond the end of the allocated buffer

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you have used the free() call inside the loop and once the memory gets free it must have to be reallocated before you can again use the free() call.
So this error is showing.
Try to use the free() outside the loop.
Hope this will help.

Comment: but once it is getting freed it agin goes in read loop and memory is allocated .. once it comes out of function then only it is getting free.. so if i use outside lloop memory leaks are dere

Comment: also if i use free inside the function only .. there is no problem.But that will not solve my requirements.

Comment: You are using realloc() after free(), I think it should be better if you use alloc() or calloc() as realloc() does not recreate the memory pointer.